# Mixing web forms and MVC - Application_Start not firing

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I user VS2015. I have an web forms (aspx) application. Some time ago, I've decided to include MVC controllers into application (and bundling). I've added code below to global.asax:

```
    public class Global : HttpApplication
  {
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // Code that runs on application startup
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
      RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
      BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Code here inside doesn't fire at all. It is added to global.asax.cs, just like in regular MVC project. How can I force this code to be run?

Comment: Is your project making use of any kind of precompilation? (especially the aspx `aspnet_compiler.exe`)? Check your `bin` folder for a `Global.asax.compiled` file which can mess with `HttpApplication` events not firing. Also try changing `Application_Start` to `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: Changing to protected helped, function is now being called. (post it as answer, I'll mark it as solution). The problem that I have now is that bundling is not being applied on controller, although it is included in master page and in controller itself (in master page all styles and in controller just the styles controller needs).